# Java dynamic matrix from Array List

Tags: java, dynamic, matrix

I'm working in java.
I have an `ArrayList<foo> myList` and i try to convert it into an array.

```
Foo[] myArray = (Foo[])myList.toArray();
```

In eclipse i'm getting the error object cannot be cast to foo.

Any solutions? I'm trying to use a dynamic allocated matrix an an `ArrayList` is not sufficient because i have to apply some sorts.

Answer (score 3):

```
 Foo[] myArray = myList.toArray(new Foo[myList.size()]);
```

Comment: `myList.toArray(new Foo[0])` is enough

Comment: Of course it is enough. But with it empty array will be created, tested that it doesn't fit and than created another array that fits. What for this empty array? To reduce amount of code in non performance-critical places?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by *matrix*, which is often used to mean a two-dimensional array, but putting that aside: if you just call `toArray()` like this, with no arguments, the returned array won't be a `Foo[]`, it'll be an `Object[]` containing your `Foo` objects. You need to use the other version of `toArray()`, the one that lets you supply your own array object, like this:

```
Foo[] myArray = myList.toArray(new Foo[myList.size()]);
```

Comment: by matrix I meant vector, sorry

Answer (score 1):

```
Foo[] myArray = (Foo[])myList.toArray(new Foo[myList.size()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this might help.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String s="hello";
    String r="world";
    myList.add(s);
    myList.add(r);
    String[] newList = myList.toArray(new String[0]);
    System.out.println(newList[0]+" "+newList[1]);  

}
```

}